# Unknow class in code, SB_Modules::loadClass in PHP website?

Tags: php

We recently took over hosting of a website where we have no knowledge of who the host was, just received the files.

Now this website makes use of Ioncube which we do not currently have installed on our web server.

If I open the index.php file I see the following code, which I can't find the source for, I assume this is a external library. If I google it I find similar code, but not any source/documentation

```
require_once('init.php');
$loadClass = SB_Modules::loadClass('Modules_Statistics');
$statisticsObject = new Modules_Statistics('a3p1kuk5rzs');
$statisticsObject->init();
$statisticsObject->processAction();
```

I tried and Google what the above code is or where it belongs to but the only thing I assume is that it needs to run on a specific enviroment or was developed to use a type of CMS or shopping cart.

Any pointers to what system it might belong to will help? Since I can't find documentation on the above.

Comment: Most likely Site Builder (not 100% sure): http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/sitebuilder/  It's a "pay for" product that commonly comes with the Plesk Control Panel. You can probably download a demo version, but otherwise you'll need to find a host with Plesk + Site Builder (I know one of my hosts has it, so there will be others around).

Comment: @Robbie - This makes sence, then it's probably not worth it if we try and host it, since we do not run either of them.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean **Ioncube**?

Comment: @Charles - hehe, typo, yes that's what I mean

Comment: @Roland, oh good, otherwise that would have been very confusing.  Even if you did have it installed ([loaders are free](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php)), Robbie is almost certainly right, and the software is unlikely to work outside of the intended environment.